# DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea in C++

Tags: c++, aero, aero-glass, dwm

I have the following C++ code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    bool fCallDWP = true;
    BOOL fDwmEnabled = FALSE;
    LRESULT lRet = 0;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    MARGINS margins;

    margins.cxLeftWidth = 10;      // 8
    margins.cxRightWidth = 10;    // 8
    margins.cyBottomHeight = 10; // 20
    margins.cyTopHeight = 50;       // 27

    hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);
    return 0;
}
```

But, when I try to compile I get the following error:

But it does not work. It does not report any error, but it simply does not show the correct result.

This is my form printscreen:

[image]

Comment: What's the value of hr after the call? According to the docs: If this function succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code.

Comment: Sincerey, I haven't tested it yet, but as soon as I can use a computer, I will test and tell you.:)

Comment: What is the output of the compiler? You said you "get the following error:", but your question does not include the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
case WM_ACTIVATE: {
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd,&margins);
    break;
}
case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
    // I think your window's transparency key should be RGB(0,0,0)
    FillRect((HDC)wParam,&WndRect,CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0)));
    return TRUE;
}
```